# How could one use Node.js to run JS from PHP and return a value back?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js

This isn't for anything serious, more so to just play around and experiment. Just not sure where I would start. Also not bound to Node.js, just figured it's the most popular server-side JS tool around.

Though if there are some major technical reasons why one shouldn't do something like this on a real site, feel free to throw them out there.

What I'm asking about is something like…

```
$input = $js_string_built_via_php;

if ($run_on_server)
     $output = node.js($input);
else
     $output = '<script type="text/javascript">'.$input.'</script>';

echo $output;
```

Comment: You want node to compile and execute a PHP-generated string of JS?

Comment: Yep, and give it back to php to toy with.

Comment: It is an interesting concept. To make things easier, I'd keep node running in the server then send a cURL with the JS string for node to execute it. Not sure how you'd pass the script contents through command-line, wait for a response and kill the process afterwards otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to know if there a limit to how long of a string one can pass through command-line?

Comment: I guess that depends on OS. Here's a generic question with some [useful answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849345/1331430) about the max length of arguments.

Comment: Of course, you could write to a JS file with php then `exec` it with `node myscript.js` to bypass those restrictions, but then I have no idea how you would fetch the output.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm using Ubuntu, so if I can get a meg into it, that's far more than enough. I haven't done any command line calls out of PHP besides ImageMagick. You don't happen to know if a command line argument receive a value back?

Comment: If I go the read/write route, I imagine I could read a file back in PHP when Node.js is done. In which case I imagine I should probably use a RAM disk to speed things up?

Comment: I imagine it is possible. Sorry my skills with php and node aren't really up to the task, but the question is pretty interesting from an experiment viewpoint.

Comment: n/p, thanks for the ideas, if I come up with anything I'll be sure to update this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several alternatives to using node here.

Have you seen the [V8js PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php), which integrates the V8 engine with PHP? I don't have any experience with using it myself, though.

Alternatively, similar to using node, you could install [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino) (available in the Ubuntu repos, at least from 12.04). Or another command line javascript interpreter. Then you can execute javascript from the shell:

```
rhino -e '<javascript code>';
```

So you should be able to do something like the following. You would have to use print to output data and then parse the output back in php somehow:

```
<?php

function execute_js($script) {
    return shell_exec('rhino -e '.escapeshellarg($script));
}

$javascript = "
    function add(a,b) {
        return a+b;
    }
    print(add(5,6));
";

$result = execute_js($javascript);

print $result;
```

I doubt this would be a good idea in a production application and seems like it might be quite vulnerable with a much greater attack surface. With clients being able to inject javascript code that actually gets executed on the server. It's probably very slow at load also.

Comment: The V8js PHP extension looks exactly what I hoped for. Thanks! Wasn't aware of this. I was thinking of possibly using it more for things like form input validation so as to not have to write duplicate code to check for valid e-mail string, etc... Also JS based templating on the server-side, like mustache, for the web crawlers seemed like a cool experiment.

Answer (score 0):

### A better solution 3 years later?

[dnode-php](https://github.com/bergie/dnode-php) would a better solution for what you want today.

There is a cool introduction [here](http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/dnode-make_php_and_node-js_talk_to_each_other/). As mentioned by the author Henri Bergius:

> DNode is a remote method invocation protocol originally written for
>   Node.js, as the name probably tells. But as the protocol itself is
>   quite simple, just sending newline-terminated JSON packets over TCP
>   connections, implementations have started popping up in other
>   languages. You can talk DNode in Ruby, Perl, Python, Java, and now
>   PHP.