# Maximum string length that can be passed in command line argument?

Tags: c++, c, command-line-arguments

I already saw this question [similar ques for SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846263/maximum-length-of-command-line-argument-that-can-be-passed-to-sqlplus-from-lin)

I am passing content of web page as argument to c++ program.

my code is here:

```
<?php
//sent has value "http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html"
$url=$_POST['sent'];
$text = file_get_contents($url);
$temp=strip_tags($text);
$output=shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/Modular/x '$temp'");
echo $output;
?>
```

Which gives output for small content only. Output I get is

```
most : 1 in : 1 investors : 1 component : 1 2013The : 1 biggest : 1 August : 1 Dynamics : 1 Herd : 1 Investor : 1 Maximum Occurrences Investor Herd Dynamics August 2013The biggest component in most investors
```

While actually it show gives count for each word.

Manually when I execute my program in command line:

```
./x "string"
```

It works and gives correct result for first paragraph  of "http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html"
. But it does not pass second and next para content in argument. It just write it on command line.

How can I pass such a content in argument? For small content it gives correct output.

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

Argument list allowed for my system is : 2097152

Comment: As an alternative to passing the entire contents as an argument, you could write the output to a file, then pass the file to the program (or, redirect the file as input. For example, write the contents to "tmp.txt" and call the program like "./x < tmp.txt").

Comment: @Alex: Thanks, But file operation will become very costly for me. I have to deal with large string and multiple such a request concurrently!

Comment: The first paragraph contains `' `, which will end the first argument of your 'x' program. You could replace all `'` by `'"'"'`.

Comment: @BryanOlivier: I tested in command line with this string `The biggest component in most investors' opinion of you`. Though it has `'` it proceed till the end of sentence!

Comment: @Karimkhan In this test did you surround the string with `"`? Note that in your PHP script your surround the string with `'`.

Comment: @BryanOlivier: Now I wrote in this way: `shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/Modular/x '"'$temp'"' ");`  which gives error : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''$temp'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/graph/sentiment_graph/data.php on line`

Comment: @Karimkhan Look into the PHP function `escapeshellarg`. I think it will solve all your problems.

Comment: @BryanOlivier: Thanks, it's very similar to my need, but `$output=shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/Modular/x .escapeshellarg($temp)");
echo $output;` does not show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your PHP program to use `escapeshellarg` as follows. I didn't test it, but my guess is that it will work

```
<?php
//sent has value "http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html"
$url=$_POST['sent'];
$text = file_get_contents($url);
$temp=escapeshellarg(strip_tags($text));
$output=shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/Modular/x " . $temp);
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot! You so sweet, please keep some nice profile picture :)

Comment: `$output=shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/Modular/x " . $temp);` is equivalent to `$output=shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/Modular/x  '$temp'");`? or which one is correct?
`

Comment: @Karimkhan My PHP knowledge is a bit rusty. But my guess is that the second is also allowed, except you shouldn't use the quotes around `$temp` as these are added by `escapeshellarg` already.

Answer (score 1):

You might modify the C++ and PHP sources and build a pipe.

C++

```
int main () {
    std::ostringstream txt;
    txt << std::cin.rdbuf();
    std::cout << "Input: \n" << txt.str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
$pipe = popen('Debug/Test', 'w'); 
if( ! $pipe) {
    // Error
} 
else { 
    $txt = 'Hello World'; 
    fwrite($pipe, $txt, strlen($txt)); 
    pclose($pipe);
}
?>
```

Comment: I like your suggestion. Too bad it fell on deaf ears. (Did `cin>>txt.rdbuf()` work? I never tried it. Also, I think the other way around makes more sense, semantically)