# Jar file doesn't get added to java classpath when appended to end

Tags: java, shell, classpath

I have an environment variable called `$CLASSPATH` which I use as the java classpath to run a certain java code.

This `$CLASSPATH` variable is quite long. Its size is about 66427 bytes ([see how long it is](http://pastebin.com/N4niwcXy))

Now this is the weird behaviour.

When I append a certain jar file (say `bar.jar`) to the **beginning** of `$CLASSPATH`, the jar file gets added to the classpath and my code runs fine.

I do this in a shell script as follows,

> CLASSPATH=/home/foo/bar.jar:$CLASSPATH

But, when I append the bar.jar at the **end** of the `$CLASSPATH`, my code gives an exception, due to missing the `bar.jar` file!

> CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/foo/bar.jar

Why this weird behaviour?

Am I missing anything here?

***Update:***

If applicable, please have a look at the output generated from `xargs --show-limits` command on shell.

```
foo@foo-laptop:~$ xargs --show-limits
Your environment variables take up 3632 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2091472
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2087840
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
```

Answer (score 1):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846263/maximum-length-of-command-line-argument-that-can-be-passed-to-sqlplus-from-lin) will help you .

It says:

Try with: `xargs --show-limits`

Your environment variables take up `2446 bytes`
`POSIX` upper limit on argument length (this system): `2092658`
`POSIX` smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): `4096`
Maximum length of command we could actually use: `2090212`
Size of command buffer we are actually using: `131072`
There is no limit per argument, but a total for the whole command line length. In my system (Fedora 15/zsh) its closer to 2Mb. (line 4).

Check the size of your resulting $CLASSPATH

Comment: Thanks ADi! Size of my `$CLASSPATH` variable is 66427 bytes. As per the output from `xargs --show-limits` command: `Your environment variables take up 3632 bytes`. Accordingly, if my $CLASSPATH size exceeds this limit of 3632, shouldn't I be getting an error or warning? However, I **do not get such an error/warning**.

Answer (score 1):

When an environment variable like `CLASSPATH` has a limit on its value length, you can try wild cards on some portions of the path.

As per documentation:

> If the directory `foo` contains `a.jar`, `b.jar`, and `c.jar`,
>   then the class path `foo/*` is expanded into
>   `foo/a.jar;foo/b.jar;foo/c.jar`, and that string would be the value of
>   the system property.

When you have so many `.class` and `.jar` files in the same path, use the following syntax:

```
CLASSPATH=/home/foo/*
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/bar/*
```

***Refer to***:

- [Understanding class path wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#env_var)

Comment: At the moment, I cannot find a way to use your suggestion, as in my case, I pick jar files using a script, one by one, based on certain conditions. However, keeping this 'wildcard' method in mind would help me someday. Thanks Ravinder!