# Best practice for submitting long commands to LSF

Tags: command-line, command, jobs, lsf

I'm submitting jobs to a cluster using `bsub` in LSF. My command calls third party software and contains a long list of files, along with other arguments (around 8000 characters).

Is it safe to submit such long commands directly or will they get truncated? Should I be saving the command to file then calling `bsub sh command.sh`?

What is the best practice for submitting such long commands.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no special limitation in LSF (that I know of) that will truncate an entire command line outright.  There are a few things you might want to consider, however:

1. The shell you run the `bsub` command in might impose a limit on the total length of the command you can submit.  This is often controlled by an OS limit, there are many questions about it floating around the internet.  [Here is one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846263/maximum-length-of-command-line-argument-that-can-be-passed-to-sqlplus-from-lin) which shows a couple of ways to determine the limit on your system.  In case of broken links, the top answer there recommends `xargs --show-limits` while another way is to check `getconf ARG_MAX`
2. Certain `bsub` options that accept strings as inputs may have limits on the length of the string that can be passed to them.  For example the `-R` option can accept strings of 512 characters -- for the most part I believe LSF will reject the job if the argument is too long (but I can't guarantee for sure if that's the case for all of them).